# How do I add an interceptor to save/fetch methods of Spring's JPARepository to update transient values?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

First let me say I'm a complete novice with Spring AOP, and I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

Here's my scenario:

Let's say I have the following domain class:

```
@Entity(name="MyTable")
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567890123456L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userID;

    @Transient
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "KEY")
    private String secureKey;

    /* Other columns */

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

and I have the following JPARepository class to manage it:

```
@Repository
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, Long> {
    /* findBy methods */
}
```

As you can see, I have a `secureKey` field and a transient `key` field. In this case `secureKey` is an encrypted version of `key`.

What I need is for the `secureKey` value to be populated before a domain object is saved, and for the `key` value to be populated after a domain object is fetched. (This is a trivial example but in the real case I have multiple transient and encrypted values.) The idea is for the secure values to be persisted to the DB, but users of the domain class will only need to work with the "insecure" values.

Currently I'm handling this in my service layer. After I call a fetch method I'm populating the transient values, and before calling a save method I'm populating the "secure" values. This is working as expected but ideally I'd like this to be managed transparently, because now the burden is on each developer to remember to update those values after fetching or before saving.

I'm assuming the best way to handle this would be through some AOP class, but I confess I have little to no idea where to begin there. Is this a common scenario, and if so, would someone be willing to point me in the right direction? Also, if you have a suggestion for a better way to implement this decrypted/encrypted field pair scenario, please let me know.

Ideally I'd like to be able to add an annotation to both the secure and insecure fields, maybe pointing to each other, maybe something like:

```
    @Insecure(secureValue = "secureKey")
    @Transient
    private String key;

    @Secure(insecureValue = "key")
    @Column(name = "KEY")
    private String secureKey;
```

Any assistance you could provide is most appreciated.

Thanks,

B.J.

Comment: You could use http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event

Comment: That is very close to what I'm looking for; it definitely seems like a better solution than forcing the service layer to manage it. I guess I could create an abstract class with methods like updateInsecureValues and updateSecureValues, marked with those callback method annotations, that use reflection to determine which fields to update, that each managed domain class would extend. Is there a simpler alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring AOP isn't the correct technology in your use case, i would recommend to use EntityListeners.

Hibernate: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Eclipselink: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#CDI_Entity_Listeners